# landscape splash screen for iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, landscape, splash-screen

i am developing an app which supports all orientations. i need to launch the splash screen (launching image) in all orientation types. but the project summary have only one field (portrait) to set the Default.png. how will i launch the landscape splash screen on my iphone app.

ipad have some features to setup both the orientations. is their anything like that in iphone,

thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iPhone splash screen is only Portrait. iPad has landscape too because iPad home screen auto rotates unlike iPhone's.

In order to achieve such a behavior you can make your first screen identical to the splash screen ( add the same image on the background) . So it will look like a landscaped splash screen while you are loading the resources needed for your app but you can't start the app in landscape mode.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: so apple really agree with that?

Comment: Yes , that is not a problem , but your app will start in Portrait. So you can change the image to the landscape one but after you get into the first screen which may take a second or two of Portrait showing.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, according to HIG, iPhone's default orientation is portrait and launch will do only portrait mode.

Comment: is their any way to implement this as custom?

Comment: you can remove portrait image too, go with black/blank for a start and then put custom controller that can show image that you want for some time. This is wrong according to HIG, but many iOS games do that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote a special behaviour

From Technical Note [TN2244 **Launching your iPhone Application in Landscape**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2244/_index.html)

> Except for launch images used by the iPhone 6 Plus, asset catalogs assume that all iPhone launch images are for the portrait orientation.

Therefore

> Launch images for iPhone apps are always sized to match the dimensions of the screen in portrait orientation. For applications that launch into landscape orientation, you should use your preferred graphics editing software to rotate the content of the launch image while keeping the image's size consistent with a portrait launch image (height > width).

if you don't do things correctly, you can end up with a blank/white screen

> The result is a blank screen during launch as the system cannot find an appropriate launch image.

Unfortunately, the document was last updated 2 years ago.

`2015-05-26  Updated for Xcode 6 and iOS 8.`