# Ionic 3 - IOS Splash Screen displayed in Portrait instead of Landscape

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I set the orientation in my app to landscape.

When I'm launching my app on IOS, the splash screen is displayed in portrait, and then the app is displayed in landscape.

Why is the splash screen displayed in portrait instead of landscape and how do I fix it?

On android the splash screen is displayed in landscape as it should.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.someId" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Some Name</name>
    <description>Some Description</description>
    <author email="someEmail@gmail.com" href="http://someDomain.com/">Some Author</author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
    <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
    <preference name="Orientation" value="landscape"/>
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
        <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
        <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="99" src="resources\wp8\icon\ApplicationIcon.png" width="99"/>
        <icon height="159" src="resources\wp8\icon\Background.png" width="159"/>
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3"/>
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="~2.0.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1"/>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git" />
</widget>
```

**Ionic info:**

```
global packages:

    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
    Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.1.1

System:

    Node       : v6.9.5
    OS         : Windows 10
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed
    npm        : 3.10.10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [landscape splash screen for iphone apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431076/landscape-splash-screen-for-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061622/launch-splash-screen-in-landscape-mode-for-iphone-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431076/landscape-splash-screen-for-iphone-apps) answer, iPhones only have portrait splash screens.

In order to solve this, you'll have to rotate your image by 90 degrees (i.e. one quarter rotation) and still call it "Portrait", that way, even though it is a "Portrait" splash screen it looks and acts as a Landscape one.

If you are using Ionics splash screen generator, then just start renaming the files. You might have to have two configs for Android/iOS, or do some things in software to compensate, however.